# Why isn't there a way to clean up my messages on Jobs?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The only two actions I see in *Jobs* is to mark a message read or unread.  I'd like to clean my "inbox" and my "sent" items, but do not see a way to archive / delete messages.

I can understand if the intention is you guys do not want to allow someone to hard delete a message, but I see no issue from soft deleting the records?

Allow soft delete of messages by setting up some sort of bit field. If it's set to true, don't show the message to the end user and maintain it in the database. The filter can specify `...WHERE IsMarkedForDeletion=0` if you just want the messages that are not marked for deletion.

Please take this as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to allow us to clean our messages folders.

[image]

Comment: Looking into this, we might be able to do something here. Stay tuned.

Comment: Found this in hot meta posts, bet myself the author will be JonH before opening this. Bet won :3

Comment: @Max - Whatever happened to this feature request?

Answer (score 4):

Good news! We've added archiving to messages now. You can archive messages from the list view or while reading an individual thread, and you view/recover your archived messages as well. There's a "select all" checkbox to help if you want to archive lots of messages at once. Also, if you get a new response on an archived thread, it'll appear in your inbox again.